# Is Regenerative Brain Tissue Technology In The Near Future?

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, molecular-genetics, neurology, stem-cells

*I got 99% of my information from articles I found in NIH's library; I can't cite anything now because I am on a timed session in a public library.*

I've been reading material from research papers in NIH's search engine, I'm no expert in this field but there's this cell called an Embryonic Stem Cell and there are 2 proteins of which I think there could be a probable chance we could utilize them to initiate and halt Stem Cell Differentiation into Neurons and Glial Cells. The 2 proteins are called Fibroblast Growth Factor-2 and Laminin-521, in the NIH article I was reading earlier today it said (paraphrase) that the suppression of FGF-2 expression resulted in ESCs (Embryonic Stem Cells) differentiating into neurons. I also read that FGF-2 maintains the pluripotent nature of stem cells and tends to prevent them from differentiating. I also infer that Laminin-521 could also be important because its important to the health of ESCs.

> Laminin 521 Stabilizes the Pluripotency Expression Pattern of Human Embryonic Stem Cells [NIH Article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5835285/#:%7E:text=PMID%3A%2029535778-,Laminin%20521%20Stabilizes%20the%20Pluripotency%20Expression%20Pattern%20of%20Human%20Embryonic,Initially%20Derived%20on%20Feeder%20Cells)

I do not think we are far away from curing things like Alzheimer's or Parkinson's disease, it's possible to reprogram adult cells into Embryonic Stem Cells, that is what the Harvard Stem Cell Institute did.

> In order to turn adult cells back into pluripotent or embryonic-like stem cells, scientists use viruses to insert four genes – Sox2, Oct4, Klf4, and cMyc – into the cells.  [Harvard Stem Cell Institute](https://hsci.harvard.edu/new-steps-forward-cell-reprogramming)

What I am saying is completely hypothetical and speculative but what if we took samples of tissue from other areas of the bodies of patients with nervous system conditions and reprogrammed them back into Embryonic Stem Cells then differentiated them into Neural and Glial Cells to make artificial brain tissue we could somehow transplant into them, or we could somehow get the stem cells to differentiate *inside* their brains. Anyways the reason I wrote this question is to get a reality check and see how plausible this actually is.

Comment: PubMed is an NIH website but things there aren't *from* the NIH, it's a library site that indexes journals. It would be like saying that Google wrote something because you found the article using Google search, or your local librarian wrote The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn because you checked that book out from the library.

Comment: @BryanKrause Oh yeah your right, I'll get that fixed.